# Storing variables inside function Matlab

Tags: function, matlab

```
function abc= calculate(obj)
ag=obj.turns*d/c;
end
```

I tried using:

```
temp=num2cell(obj.turns)
            s=temp{:}
```

But the value is replaced every time.

How can I store the value of obj.turns in this function? The value changes every time the function is called.

Comment: Your above code is broken (Where does `ag` go?  What do `d` and `c` come from?).  And it's not clear what you mean by "storing a variable in a function"; you're passing it as a parameter, so why do you need to "store" it?

Comment: ag is used in next functions, it calculates circuit parameters. All of these symbols correspond to some objects that do change their values. What I want is to plot the value of obj.turns not in this function but in the main m file

Comment: I don't think you quite understand the meaning of a function, because that just doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 4):

If I interpret what you want correctly, you should use a [persistent variable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/persistent.html). Here's an example:

```
function abc = calculate(obj)

  persistent storedTurns;
  if isempty(storedTurns)
    storedTurns = obj.turns;
  end

  ag = storedTurns*d/c;
  ...

end
```

The first time you call `calculate`, the value in `obj.turns` will be placed in `storedTurns`. That value will stay fixed for every other time you call `calculate`, ignoring from that point on whatever new values may be present in the variable `obj` that you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

For a persistant variable (one that exists beyond the scope of the function) like the one you require, you'll need to either make another class property to hold it, or update the existing object like in this example.

```
function obj = increment_x(obj) 
    obj.x=obj.x+1;
end
```

This is a simple function that increments the value of x. The important detail is that the function also returns the object.

Alternatively, you can make your class a subclass of the handle class. Object properties are then modified in place, so you can get away with something like the following . . .

```
function increment_x(obj) 
    obj.x=obj.x+1;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be done.

Pass in all variables into the function (Preferred method).

```
function ag= calculate(obj,d,c)
ag=obj.turns*d/c;
end
```

Use global variables. This can be very confusing, and so it not recommended.

```
function calculate(obj)
global ag,d,c
ag=obj.turns*d/c;
end
```

And some other code:

```
function start
global ag,d,c
c=1;d=3;
calculate(obj)
fprintf('%i',ag);
```

Comment: d and c are actually objects..ie obj.m_cross_section and obj.m_inductance. Declaring them global is giving an error a red line underneath